# ошибка при загрузке видео на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

вот ошибка каторая возникаєт при загрузке видео, раньше все грузило, когда добавил новиє поля, то перевищує допустимий размер, хотя видео имеет всего 49000 кб:
 POST Content-Length of 50794588 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

вот код:

## Додати новину

```
   <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
?> <div id="oblik_error"><?php echo $_SESSION['msg'];?></div><?php
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
?>
  <br/> 
  <br/> 
  <br/> 
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="new_artickle" method="POST" action="includes/set_news.php" >
    <label>Назва статті:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" /><br/>

    <label>Повний текст:</label><br/>
    <textarea name="full_text" rows="30" cols="120" style="resize: none; font-size: 16px; font-family: Times New Roman;"></textarea><br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>        <br/>
<div style="border: 1px solid grey; padding: 15px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: #CEFFFF;">
          <label style="font-size: 20px;">Додати головне зображення:</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"/>

        <br/><br/><hr/><br/><label style="font-size: 20px;">Додати проміжні зображення:</label>
        <input type="file" name="image_more[]" multiple accept="image/*"/>


   <br/><br/><hr/><br/>
   <label style="font-size: 20px;">Додати ссилку на сайт:</label>
   <input type="text" name="url" style="margin-left: 30px; width: 682px; " disabled/>
  <br/><hr/><br/>
   <label style="font-size: 20px;">Додати ссилку на відео YouTube:</label>
   <input type="text" name="youtube" style="margin-left: 30px; width: 600px; "/>
   <hr/><br/>
    <label style="font-size: 20px;">Додати файли:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 682px;" multiple/>
```

---

Додати відео:

```
    <input type="submit" name="set_new" value="Опублікувати новину" id="set_new"/>
</form>  
<br/><br/>

<br>
 <center id="message" style="position: inherit; margin-left: -20px;"></center>
```

Comment: НУ правильно - у тебя 50 мегабайт данных, а входной буфер всего 8 мегабайт, вшестеро меньше.

Comment: Меняйте настройки php.ini `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize`.